# Screen glitches and freezes + system errors after dropping laptop

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, freeze

I'm using a HP Pavillion 14-ce3003nf.

After I've dropped it on my bed while standing up (which should not be a problem at all), the screen started glitching and froze.
I can't tell if the system itself stopped or if it was just the screen.
The reboots changed nothing to it. After a random amount of minutes, the thing always occurs. On ubuntu, everything just stops. On Windows, I get a blue screen.

A video on YouTube made me replug the RAM. (the guy changed it slot, but i have only one of them).

Idk if it's worth mentioning my battery is not in a good shape, but it's always been like this. Could it be the source of it? The battery is the only issue, HP system and components scans detected.

You can some errors thrown by Ubuntu right during the freeze (pic) and on boot (video):
[image: Errors]